# Grep with ruby the gemlist

Tags: ruby, regex, bundler

I'm trying to grep a gem list. I get the list with

```
bundlelist = `bundle show`
```

Result

```
"Gems included by the bundle:\n  * CFPropertyList (2.3.1)\n  * abstract_type (0.0.7)\n  * actionmailer (4.2.3)\n  * actionpack (4.2.3)\n"
```

I would like:

```
=> ["CFPropertyList",
 "abstract_type",
 "actionmailer",
 "actionpack"]
```

When I try to grep on it, I do `bundlelist.scan(/\*.*\(/)`. The result is:

```
=> ["* CFPropertyList (",
 "* abstract_type (",
 "* actionmailer (",
 "* actionpack ("]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lookbehind and lookahead instead:

```
/(?<=\* ).*?(?= \()/
```

What this means is the minimum thing that is preceded by *star + space* and followed by *space + opening bracket*.

Comment: I've added bundlelist result. When trying your proposition. bundlelist.scan(/(?<=\* ).*?(?= \(/)
SyntaxError: (eval):2: end pattern with unmatched parenthesis: /(?<=\* ).*?(?= \(/

Comment: @BeniMio, there was a little mistake. I fixed it. Try to use the new version (added `)` at the end).